# How can we include aggregate functions in expression of PowerBI paginated report when data set does not have aggregated result?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

We are using the embedded PowerBI reports in our application. As we have to provide the download option to end user, we are planning to move to paginated reports and want to use the same data set for generating it.

Our data set is having individual entries, which looks like below for example.

[image]

The expected result is,

[image]

Currently in PowerBI report we use below measures

[image]

We are getting errors, when aggregate function are included in expressions.

Is there anyway to write similar expressions to achieve this result in paginated report OR the data set has to be changed?